# CiviCRM Webforms - Webform submission value shows the field id instead of the value of the id

Tags: webform-civicrm, email, tokens

I have a problem with one of the fields in a notification email for CiviCRM Webforms.

I’m using a Drupal Webform which includes CiviCRM contact fields.  These fields include a number of fields that make up the postal address.

One of these fields is the State/Province.  The key is: civicrm_1_contact_1_address_state_province_id

I’ve included that field in the Webform email: [webform_submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_address_state_province_id]

The problem is that when the email is sent, the value for the State/Province is shown as “1644” instead of “Victoria”.

All the other Webform submission values in the email are correct.

This was working as expected under Drupal 7 but we recently migrated to Drupal 9 and we are now seeing the wrong value for the State/Province.

The strange thing is that if we do a resend of the email, the correct value is shown.

Comment: oh. that is odd that resending gives the correct value

Answer (score 2):

I’ve not found a way of getting Drupal/CiviCRM to populate the email token with the text of the State/Province.  It always comes out as the index number.

However, I’ve figured out a workaround.  I’ve added a text field to the Webform and I then hide the field from the user.  I then run some JavaScript to copy the value of the CiviCRM State/Province field into the hidden field.  This gives me the text for the selected item.  I then use that field id in the email instead of the CiviCRM field id.

Happy to share the JavaScript code but I'm new to StackExchange and I don't know how to do this.